# Spark error : parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDictionary$PlainIntegerDictionary

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive

I am having trouble with reading a spark dataframe from a hive table. I stored the dataframe as:

```
dataframe.coalesce(n_files).write.option("mergeSchema", "true").mode("overwrite").parquet(table_path)
```

When I try to read this dataframe and do a `.show()`  on it, it breaks with the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDictionary$PlainIntegerDictionary
at parquet.column.Dictionary.decodeToLong(Dictionary.java:52)
```

How I can I find which column is the root cause of this error?
I tried to follow the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53149457/java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-error-in-spark-when-writing) . But I am able to load the df perfectly fine reading the parquet files viz:

```
df = spark.read.option("mergeSchema", "True").parquet("/hdfs path to parquets")
```

- The said hive table is an external table. My guess is it has something to do with table properties? But what should I be looking at?
- I cannot use `saveAsTable`. I need to write directly to the path due to a [certain requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38964736/multiple-spark-jobs-appending-parquet-data-to-same-base-path-with-partitioning)

Answer (score 12):

Found the root cause of my problem. Posting my findings here so someone in need can check if their case is the same.

I encountered this issue because of the difference in datatypes in hive table metadata and the parquets. The thing is when you do a `saveAsTable` spark will typecast your data while saving, if there is any difference. But when you do a `df.write.parquet(path)` you are writing your parquets directly to the path, so if there is a mismatch between the table metadata and the parquets, `df.show` will throw an error.

For example, if your table metadata has dtype `'bigint'` for column A, but the df you're trying to save has dtype `IntegerType` for the same column (instead of `LongType`, which is the correct interpretation for `bigint`), a `saveAsTable` would typecast `IntegerType` to `LongType` but `df.write.parquet(path)` won't.

**The solution is to typecast your problematic column to the dtype that matches with the metadata of the table.**

Comment: super useful thanks @Ayush Goyal - are you able to point us to how you arrived at the root case?